# hightchart.js is not plotting graph in IE11

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-material

I am using Highchart.js version `7.2.0` with Angular version `6.0.3` and Angular-Material version `6.4.7`. The charts are plotting fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11. Below are the screenshots:

IE11:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

I tried many solutions looking at internet but none of those worked for me.

Comment: can you add es-shims/es5-shim and try?

Comment: please examine https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39944

Comment: @ahmeticat I am already having the `<!doctype html>` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">` in index.html.

Comment: @GauravSharma I tried `import 'core-js/es5';` in polyfills.ts but still same result.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in an online code editor like codesandox? You can use this example as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4